# Why next function in beforeRouteEnter happends after the component is loaded?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In `beforeRouteEnter` event I call to promise/http which take a second to get some data.

After I get the data I pass to the `result` prop in the component. (using `next` function).

Also I have a getter that take the value from the prop.

The problem is vue is invoke the getter before it set the value (by `next` function), so I got `undefined`.

How can I solve this error?

Here is an [code example of the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-typescript-example-cb9o0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when you use next(vm ...) you work with context of page component where is your @Prop defined. You can't modify @Prop value this way. There is some hacks how you can do that but is it really necessary to use @Prop in this case? Why you simply don't use basic variable in page component?

If you replace

```
@Prop() result
```

with:

```
result: Object = {};
```

everything works great.

If you really need prop here maybe you can just copy prop value to some variable (use watch if you need detect changes) but i don't see any purpose for prop here.

Hope this answer helps you :)